# Python: uMongo sort

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, umongo

I am using [uMongo](https://umongo.readthedocs.io/en/fix_readthedocs/apireference.html) with Python 3.0
I have this model:

```
class Job(Document):
    priority = IntField()
```

I'm using:

```
jobs = Job.find()
```

To get all jobs from mongo instance, and I am trying to sort them by priority.. but unfortunely, I can't seem to find the way to do it. I've searched the [docs](https://umongo.readthedocs.io/en/fix_readthedocs/apireference.html) & googled it, tried bunch of things like

```
jobs = Job.find().sort('priority', 1)
jobs = Job.find().order_by('priority')
```

and lot of other solutions I found related to pymongo which doesn't work with uMongo.

but still stuck.. any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not used `umongo` before, but upon examination, I found that the find() method actually returns a `umongo.frameworks.pymongo.WrappedCursor` instance. And looking into [the code](https://github.com/Scille/umongo/blob/master/umongo/frameworks/pymongo.py#L16) it seems to me that this is just a pymongo.cursor with some goodies included. So, I did the following experiment and it worked. Please let me know if this helps or not.

1.> I created a collection called `marketing` (Why this name? I do not know :) ) It looks like following
[image: marketing collection]

2.> As you can see that it is not ordered as per the priority field.

3.> Then I wrote the following code

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: from pymongo import MongoClient

In [3]: from umongo import Instance, Document, fields, validate

In [4]: db = MongoClient().test_db

In [5]: instance = Instance(db)

In [6]: @instance.register
   ...: class Marketing(Document):
   ...:     priority = fields.IntField()
   ...:     class Meta:
   ...:         collection = db.marketing
```

4.> Then I tried the normal for loop (without sorting)

```
    In [8]: for doc in Marketing.find():
   ...:     print(doc)
   ...:     
<object Document __main__.Marketing({'id': ObjectId('5a1bf2acc24bf00f20acb2a2'), 'priority': 1})>
<object Document __main__.Marketing({'id': ObjectId('5a1bf2d1c24bf00f20acb2af'), 'priority': 3})>
<object Document __main__.Marketing({'id': ObjectId('5a1bf2e0c24bf00f20acb2b8'), 'priority': 2})>
<object Document __main__.Marketing({'id': ObjectId('5a1bf2eec24bf00f20acb2ba'), 'priority': 5})>
<object Document __main__.Marketing({'id': ObjectId('5a1bf2f4c24bf00f20acb2bc'), 'priority': 4})>
```

5.> Of course the documents are returned in the same order as they are present in the collection.

6.> Finally, I changed the for loop to sort the documents.

```
    In [9]: import pymongo

    In [11]: for doc in Marketing.find().sort([("priority", pymongo.ASCENDING)]):
    ...:     print(doc)
    ...:     
    ...:     
<object Document __main__.Marketing({'id': ObjectId('5a1bf2acc24bf00f20acb2a2'), 'priority': 1})>
<object Document __main__.Marketing({'id': ObjectId('5a1bf2e0c24bf00f20acb2b8'), 'priority': 2})>
<object Document __main__.Marketing({'id': ObjectId('5a1bf2d1c24bf00f20acb2af'), 'priority': 3})>
<object Document __main__.Marketing({'id': ObjectId('5a1bf2f4c24bf00f20acb2bc'), 'priority': 4})>
<object Document __main__.Marketing({'id': ObjectId('5a1bf2eec24bf00f20acb2ba'), 'priority': 5})>
```

7.> As you can see, they are returned in the sorted order.

I am not 100% sure that this corresponds to your case or not. But from the question, it looks like.

Comment: Looks like this should do the job